# How to retrieve playerGroup attribute from GKTurnBasedMatch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mobile, gamekit

There are three different levels in my game that a user can choose.  I have saved the player's chosen level in the playerGroup attribute of GKMatchRequest.  After a match has been made, how do I retrieve the playerGroup from the GKTurnBasedMatch, or is there a different way to keep track of which game level a match is?

Answer (score 1):

After you create your GKMatchRequest, you must call findMatchForRequest. In the completion handler for findMatchForRequest, you can store the level of your game in the new match's matchData property.

Answer (score 1):

I use GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController for presenting automatch/invite UI. When creating a GKMatchRequest, I add an ObjC-associated playerGroup value (packed into an NSNumber) to the GKTBMVC like this:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.playerGroup = somePlayerGroup;
GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
objc_setAssociatedObject(mmvc,
                         &kPlayerGroupKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithInteger:request.playerGroup],
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

[myViewController presentViewController:mmvc
                               animated:YES
                             completion:nil];
```

Then in `turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:didFindMatch:` delegate method I read the `playerGroup` value to know what kind of match we need to set up or join:

```
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)mmvc didFindMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
{
     [myViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                          completion:^{
                                              NSNumber *n = objc_getAssociatedObject(mmvc, &kPlayerGroupKey);
                                              NSInteger playerGroup = [n integerValue];
                                              [self switchToMatch:match matchKind:playerGroup];
                                          }];
}
```

Of course, you can store `playerGroup` in `match.matchData` when creating a new match, but sometimes it is more convenient to pass it with the matchmaking view controller.